# How to use VBA to get some information from a webpage

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

This is my code:

```
Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 
    Dim doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument 
    
   ie.navigate "http://vpcqcsdt.bocongan.gov.vn/Truy-n%C3%A3-TP/%C4%90%E1%BB%91i-t%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3ng-truy-n%C3%A3"
    Do Until (Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        DoEvents
    Loop
   
 Set doc = ie.document
    
  Set doc1 = doc.getElementById("dnn_ctr1088_MainForm_lblRowCount")
   
   
    Myvalue = doc1.innerText
```

-- This return "Tổng số 10873 đối tượng đình nã trong 218 trang"

in html: Tổng số **10873** đối tượng đình nã trong **218** trang

but I dont know how to get only two numbers: 10873 and 218  which are counts

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question, include your code attempt and explain what is not working in details.

Comment: This is the code in html: <span id="dnn_ctr1088_MainForm_lblRowCount" class="count">Tổng số <strong>10873</strong> đối tượng đình nã trong <strong>218</strong> trang</span>

Comment: Please edit your question and include the HTML. Also, you need to make your own attempt first and show us your full code. @TranThanhTu

Comment: My code 

Set doc = ie.document 
Set doc1 = doc.getElementById("dnn_ctr1088_MainForm_lblRowCount")

It returns the whole innerText

but how can I do if I only need two numbers: 1087 AND 218

Comment: At a guess, what you can try following `Set doc...` is `doc.getElementsByTagName("strong")(0)` for the first value and `doc.getElementsByTagName("strong")(1)` for the second value.

Comment: Many tks but it does not work. "strong" here is to get the number Bold

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention `innerText` property so it should be `doc.getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText` and `doc.getElementsByTagName("strong")(1).innerText` @TranThanhTu

Comment: It is perfect! many tks Raymond
 my final code:
Set element = doc.getElementById("dnn_ctr1088_MainForm_lblRowCount")

        
       abc = element.getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText
       
       
       def = element.getElementsByTagName("strong")(1).innerText
       MsgBox abc
       MsgBox def

Comment: Hi @TranThanhTu, if you solved your problem, post your code as an answer. If you can, please also write why that worked.